# 'range' object does not support item assignment - trying to use old python code in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, variable-assignment

I am trying to run an old python code made with python 2.7(?) in python 3.3 and I'm stuck on updating the code to run. It keeps telling me "'range' object does not support item assignment" and for the life of I cannot figure it out. The code is for a "50 states trivia" game I found on google.

The error is at the line `answer[i] = "%s " % flower[pick[i]].rstrip()`

```
 pick = random.sample(range(50), 4)

print("The state flower of %s is:" % state[pick[0]])
answer = range(4)
for i in range(4):
    if i == 0:
        answer[i] = "%s " % flower[pick[i]].rstrip()
    else:
        answer[i] = "%s" % flower[pick[i]].rstrip()
```

BTW, this code is [HERE](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216717/build-a-state-trivia-game-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484195/typeerror-range-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
answer = list(range(4))
```

to allow modifications

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm having all kinds of problems. Maybe someone could take a look at the original code (I added a link)? I'm getting a "local variable 'correct' referenced before assignment", and none of the multiple choice answers are displaying, just numbers.

Comment: @Andrew No worries, but sorry this site doesn't look at links, we need questions to be self contained. If you would like you can submit a new question :)